# Push Notification not seen at Eclipse Android Emulator

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

I am using the PARSE TI CC3200 Quickstart running at Code Composer Stdio, and I want to send push notifications to Eclipse Android Emulator. But, I am having difficulties accomplishing this.

Here is parse code at CCS from quickstart:

```
parseSendRequest(client,
                 "POST",
                 "/1/classes/TestObject",
                 "{\"foo\":\"Markel Markel Markel\"}",
                 NULL);

parseSetPushCallback(client, myPushCallback);
parseStartPushService(client);

parseRunPushLoop(client);
```

Here is eclipse code ParseApplication.java

```
package com.makemyandroidapp.parsenotificationexample;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

import android.app.Application;

public class ParseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, Keys.applicationId, Keys.clientKey);
        PushService.subscribe(this, "TestObject", MainActivity.class);
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    }

}
```

The message is in TestObject class -> foo. With this code above there is no output at Eclipse Android Emulator. How do I output the message at Eclipse Android Emulator?

Best Regards,
Markel

Comment: is Parse require google play services?

Comment: No. it does not require google play servies, @Markel try to run it in a physical devie or gennymotion emulator, and check if you have given correct permissions in manifest

Comment: No. Parse provides cloud services like push notifications to your android device. See. parse.com in the internet.

Comment: I have given correct app id and client key. I use this blog post as one of my guide. http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/how-to-create-android-avd-emulator-in-eclipse/. But, I do not want to use Temboo. What I am doing is sending a push notification from my TI CC3200 Launchpad to Parse to my Eclipse Android Emulator.